# Getting the center of a model (position, scale and rotation)

Tags: opengl, matrix, position

I'm starting looking a tutorial of openGL and to create the entities of the world, is using a generic class which just saves three things: the position, scale and rotation of the element. With it, any time is going to render the element, creates a model matrix multiplying these three things.

My question is: how can I get the central position of this element with this three things?

For instance, we have an element at the (0, 0, 0) position with a scale of (10, 10, 10) and a rotation of (0, 0, 0). How do I know whats the central position? Does it depend on the camera or something like that? How can I get this absolute central position?

[image]

EDIT:

More info:

```
float ar = getAspectRatio();
cam->setOrthoParams(ar*-100.f, ar*100.f, -100.f, 100.f, -100.0f, 100.f);
```

With this, how can I calculate the bounding box?

Comment: This is only the cameras parameters, it tells nothing about the element.

Comment: But it defines the width/height of the object right? If the world width is 100px, and the scale of an object is 20px, then it is like the 20% of the world. Isn't it?

Comment: I just need to know the relation between the scale and the camera...

Comment: The scale multiplies the object's original size. If the original object's x size is 10px and the x scale is 6, then it's final x size will be 60px. But to find out the original size, you have to know the mesh data.

Comment: If you are using ngl, then item->calcDimensions() will count the bounding box for you, and after it item->getBBox() will give you the bounding box and item->getCenter() the vertex weighted center.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the model geometry too if you want to calculate some kind of geometric center.

For example calculating the bounding box center: loop through all untransformed vertices and find minimal and maximal X,Y,Z values. Their averages will define the bounding box center. Then you can apply the position and scale transformation to this point, and you get the transformed center.

Comment: The case is, It doesnt take into account any kind of width or height of the image. It just uses the scale... the ortho params are 100. I edited my post with more info... i need to calculate the bounding box, yes.